# LESS inheritance from siblings nested class

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to get the styles form `.my-class` and put it in `.child-1`, can someone guide me through this?

I need to inherit those styles because in my projects those are fairly big :)

```
.parent {
 .child-1 {
  //inherit
 }

 .child-2 {
  .my-class {
    //some_styles
  }
 }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated !! Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend it like
    `&:extend(.my-class);`

or you can use mixins
    `.my-class();`

These are both similar but mixins have the added bonus of being able to pass variables to them so you can use them like functions.

Comment: Interesting, but the thing is that when I am using extend, it works completely fine, but when I am writing using mixins it says that .my-class() is not defined.( In case, I am working in node env)

Comment: Either `extend` (unless you're using [`extend all`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-)) and mixin forms require complete "path" to the invoked ruleset (i.e. `.child-2 .my-class` in this case). See [Extending Nested Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extending-nested-selectors), [Namespaces](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-namespaces) etc.